# Как записать строку string в файл?

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::ifstream in("D:\\laba13.txt");
    std::ofstream f("D:\\laba130.txt");
    std::getline(in, str);
    std::istringstream ist(str);
    std::string word;
    while (ist >> word) 
    {
        const char lastCh = word.back();
        std::remove_copy(word.begin(), word.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), lastCh);
        std::cout << lastCh << " ";
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Программа удаляет предыдущие вхождения последней буквы в словах.
Я считываю строку из файла, это мне сделать удалось, но записать результат в другой файл у меня не выходит. Нужно, чтобы результат шел в файл, а не на консоль. Нужно как-то заменить std::cout?? Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: помоему просто f << lastch;

Comment: просто  f << lastch; не работает, вообще ничего в файл не записывает

Comment: @Виктория Армстронг: Вы что-то выдумываете. `f << lastch;` работает прекрасно и все записывает в файл.

Answer (score 1):

> Просто `f << lastch;` не работает, вообще ничего в файл не записывает

У половины комментирующих работает нормально, у половины работает только с `f.close()`, хотя файлы якобы должны закрываться автоматически при выходе из программы.

Вопрос старый, но раз уж его подняли на главную страницу, напишу ответ. Может кому-то пригодится.

---

`std::ofstream` обычно делает запись в файл НЕ сразу после вызова `<<`.

Вместо этого, чтобы запись происходила быстрее, он использует *буферизацию* - накапливает в памяти (в так называемом буфере) поступающие символы, и время от времени (по умолчанию - когда встречает символ `\n`) разом записывает их на диск (после чего буфер очищается и процесс повторяется).

Когда файл закрывают, содержимое буфера также записывается на диск.

Когда объект `std::ofstream` уничтожается, файл закрывается автоматически (в вашем случае это происходит при выходе из `main`.

Проблема здесь в том, что **если программа встает на `_getch()`** (или чем-то похожем) **и ее закрывают на крестик**, она обычно завершается немедленно. При таком ненормальном завершении работы **файлы не закрываются должным образом** (потому что деструкторы для объектов не вызываются) **и содержимое их буферов не записывается на диск и теряется**.

Если нажать любую клавишу (или <kbd>Ввод</kbd>, в случае `std::cin.get()`) и дать программе завершиться нормально, проблем не будет.

<sup>(Видимо отсюда разногласия в комментариях. Часть людей нажимала <kbd>Ввод</kbd>, часть - крестик.)</sup>

Если сильно хочется закрывать программу на крестик, нужно заранее закрывать файлы самому, через `f.close();`. Либо делать `<< std::flush` после вывода.

Answer (score 0):

Так на g++ 7.1 все работает. Абсолютные пути к файлам намертво вклеивать в программу не очень хорошо, поэтому я их поменял на относительные. И просто добавил копию Вашего вывода на экран для файла.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::ifstream in("laba13.txt");
    std::ofstream f("laba130.txt");
    std::getline(in, str);
    std::istringstream ist(str);
    std::string word;
    while (ist >> word) 
    {
        const char lastCh = word.back();
        std::remove_copy(word.begin(), word.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), lastCh);
        std::remove_copy(word.begin(), word.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(f), lastCh);
        std::cout << lastCh << " ";
        f << lastCh << " ";
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если закрыть файл, то работает(код проверил):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::ifstream in("laba13.txt");
    std::ofstream f("laba130.txt");
    std::getline(in, str);
    std::istringstream ist(str);
    std::string word;
    while (ist >> word)
    {
        const char lastCh = word.back();
        std::remove_copy(word.begin(), word.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), lastCh);
        std::remove_copy(word.begin(), word.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(f), lastCh);
        std::cout << lastCh << " ";
        f << lastCh << " ";
    }
    f.close(); // важно!
    in.close();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: При выходе из программы файлы будут закрыты автоматически. Для такой маленькой программы это не настолько принципиально. Кроме того, если уж беретесь поправлять, будьте последовательны - Вы забыли закрыть и входной поток ;-) .

Comment: Оказалось принципиально. Ну, вот честно, ваш пример у меня не заработал. А заработал только с таким исправлением. ОС: macOS