# c++ работа с файлами

Tags: c++, файлы, потоки-данных

Когда вывожу в файл данные (язык - c++), через fstream, они появляется в нём только после того, как я этот файл закрою (то есть, если ofstream file, то информация в нём появляется только после того, как file.close()). Как сделать так, чтобы информация в нём обновлялась автоматически после каждого вывода, т. к. так удобнее выполнять пошаговую отладку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызвать `file.flush()` и сбросить буфер.

Также буфер можно сбросить, отправив в поток `std::flush`.

```
file << std:flush;
```

`std::endl` кроме вставки новой строки также вызывает `flush`

Comment: Спасибо большое, я везде переходил на новую строку через "\n", поэтому не обновлялось

Comment: В этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791184/Как-записать-строку-string-в-файл/791251#791251) была такая же проблема.

Comment: @GarfieldCat приведенный Вами вопрос совершенно о другом

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov можете тогда объяснить почему не срабатывала запись в файл до момента добавления операции закрытия?